# Show set closed (check proof and and help with alternative proof)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, proof-writing

$g : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ be the function $g(x) = x + 1$. The subset $G$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, is defined as $G=\{(x,g(x))|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. I want to show that this is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ using defintion of closed.

---

A set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open if $\forall x\in X, \exists\:r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq\:X$.

A set $X\subseteq\:\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed if $X^C$ is open. $\:\:$ ($X^c$ is complement of $X$).

A set $X\subseteq\:\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed iff every sequence in $X$ that converges (to some element $\mathbb{R}^n$) has its limit in $X$.

I was to show that $G$ is closed since $G^C$ is open.

Here's what I have so far:

$G=\{(x,x+1)|x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Let $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}×\mathbb{R}\G$, the complement of $G$. Since $(x,y)\notin G$, we have $y\neq g(x)$. Then I get stuck... Showing $G^C$ open is my weaker area. I was hoping to get some help on this.

.

I also tried to show it's closed using the convergence limit definition too, but I want to figure out the complement open argument still.

Here's what I have for limit convergence definition:

Let $\{(x_n, g(x_n))\}$ be a convergent sequence in $G$, say $(x_n, g(x_n)) \to (x,y)$.  So $x_n \to x$.  So $g(x_n) \to g(x)$.  So $g(x) = y$, and so $(x_n, g(x_n)) \to (x, g(x)) \in G$.  So $G$ is closed.

Is this good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you an argument, and let you fill in the details. Let $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\setminus G$. Since $G$ is a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^2$, construct a line passing through $(x,y)$ which is perpendicular to $G$. This line will intersect $G$ at the point $(a,b)\in G$ which is closest to $(x,y)$, and since $(x,y)\notin G$, the distance $d$ between the points is greater than zero. Then simply take a ball of radius $r=\frac{d}{2}$. Since $d$ was the distance between $(x,y)$ and the line, the ball $B((x,y),r)$ does not intersect the line, and so $B((x,y),r)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\setminus G$. Thus, as $(x,y)$ was arbitrary, $G$ is closed.

I'd like to point out, however, that a sequence argument like you did is much neater here, and is really easy to generalize to show that the graph of any continuous function in closed. Indeed let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be closed and consider

$$\operatorname{graph}(f)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : y=f(x)\}.$$

Let $\{(x_n,y_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\operatorname{graph}(f)$ with limit $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then, by continuity

$$y=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\right)=f(x).$$

Thus $(x,y)\in\operatorname{graph}(f)$, and so $\operatorname{graph}(f)$ is closed.

Comment: when would the limit argument be better than the ball-radius one, and vice-verse? For sets of functions would it be best to use the limit one and for more abstract ones, use the ball-radius one?

Comment: Honestly it is a very case-by-case thing. Some sets are defined in such a way that the ball definition is better suited, and some are easier to deal with using the sequential characterisation. Usually when you're dealing with continuous functions, you can expect the sequential characterization at least, but it really depends.